# A random variable X is normal with mean $\mu = 5$ and variance $\sigma^2 = 4.$ Find the pdf $f_X(x|(x − 4)^2<9)$ using the normal table.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

A random variable X is normal with mean $\mu = 5$ and variance $\sigma^2 = 4.$ Find the probability density function $f_X(x|(x − 4)^2<9)$ using the normal table.

**MY WORKING**

$f_X(x|(x − 4)^2<9)=f_X(x|1<x<7)=f_X(7)-f_X(1)$

The issue is the question tells that the answer is one of the following four & my result doesn't match any of the them , which are:

$\text{(a)} \frac{f_X(7)−f_X(1)}{0.8185}, 1 \le x \le 7$

$\text{(b)} \frac{f_X(x)}{0.8185}$, for any $x$

$\text{(c)} \frac{f_X(x)} {0.8185}, 1 \le x \le 7$

$\text{(d)} \frac{f_X(x)} {0.1815}, 1 \le x \le 7$

However it matches slightly with the option $(a)$, but I don't understand where the denominator $0.8185$ comes from?

Any help or guidance will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to find $f_X(x|(x-4)^2<9)$, that is $f_X(x|1<x<7)$.
Intuitively, our distribution will still be a normal. However, it will be limited to the interval $x\in[1,7]$.

Therefore, the new pdf will be of the form $f_{X|1<x<7}(x)=cf_X(x) I_{[1,7]}(x)$, where c is a constant such that:
$$
\int_{1}^7
cf_X(x)\:dx=1 
$$
Substituting and computing the result we get that:
$$
\int_1^7 c \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x-5}{2})^2} = 0.8185
$$
and therefore $c=\frac{1}{0.8185}$.
So the right answer is c.